# How to pass kwargs to another kwargs in python?

Tags: python

```
def a(**akwargs):
    def b(bkwargs=akwargs):
        # how to not only use akwargs defaultly,but also define bkwargs by
        # myself?
        print bkwargs
    return b
```

If I wanna make the following function realized. how could I do with the code above?

```
>>>a(u='test')()
{'u': test}

>>>a(u='test')(u='test2')
{'u': test2}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uses the kwargs from the outer function as default, and updates kwargs passed to the inner function.

```
from functools import partial

def outer(**kwargs):
    def inner(**kwargs):
        return(kwargs)
    return partial(inner, **kwargs)
```

This next one uses the kwargs from the outer function if no kwargs was assigned to the inner.

```
def outer(**outer_kwargs):
    def inner(**inner_kwargs):
        kwargs = inner_kwargs or outer_kwargs
        return kwargs
    return inner
```

Comment: the second one is excellent,that's extremely what i want,thank you.

Answer (score 4):

It's a little unclear what you want, but I think this is the trick:

```
def a(**akwargs):
    def b(bkwargs=akwargs, **kwargs):
        # how to not only use akwargs defaultly,but also define bkwargs by
        # myself?
        if not bkwargs:
            bkwargs = kwargs
        else:
            # it depends what you want here (merge or replace?), but probably
            # something like bkwargs.update(kwargs) or kwargs.update(bkwargs)
    return b
```

Comment: The solution works, but I find it the most clumsy solution here, don't you think using `partial` gives you a more clean solution?

Comment: @brunsgaard Can we make `a(u='test')(v='test2')` gives `{'v': 'test2'}` with `functools`?

Comment: @WKPlus, yeah, that is exactly what happens ;)

Comment: @brunsgaard nope, with the code in your answer, it gives `{'u': 'test', 'v': 'test2'}` not `{'v': 'test2'}`

Comment: yeah, you are mixing 'u' and 'v'.. don't you med 'u' both places? I thought it was a typo in your end. If you dont wanna send the outer kwargs to the inner function, just return the inner function without partial.

Comment: We can not identify whether he/she want to update or just replace  kwargs. But wim's answer works both. If update, `functools` works fine and cool :)

Comment: @WKPlus, I agree, but I do not think you are answering the question LeoTao asked. See the update to my answer, now there is both solutions, and I find mine more elegant ;)

Answer (score 1):

Why not do the following?

```
def a(**akwargs):
    def b(**bkwargs):
        allkwargs = {}
        allkwargs.update(akwargs)
        allkwargs.update(bkwargs)
        print allkwargs
    return b
```

This uses the values from `a` but allows you to overwrite it by passing more to `b`. So:

```
>>> a(u='test')()
{'u': 'test'}
>>> a(u='test')(u='test2')
{'u': 'test2'}
```

Comment: If the OP want `a(u='test')(v='test2')` gives `{'v': 'test2'}` not `{'u': 'test', 'v': 'test2'}`, this will not work.

Comment: @WKPlus I thought the intent was to use the first kwargs as defaults and augment those with the second kwargs (and overwriting keys) if needed. If that's not the intent then this won't be a good function.

Comment: @WKPlus you really caught my intent.